# How to access a variable state from the defining function rather than the calling object

Tags: javascript

eg:

```
func = (){

    var i_want_this = "yes";

    var callback = function(){
        // I want to access value of i_want_this here
        // Preferably just the single variable without the whole scope
    };

    obj.subfunc(some_stuff, callback);

};


obj = {

    subfunc = function(stuff, callback){

        // do stuff

        callback();

    }

};

func();
```

Comment: You haven't tried to run the code, have you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the variable in the callback; it will work the way you want it to.

This is called a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).